# Library for integrate webcam with java

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu-11.04

I have project for making application which integrate webcam with Java Language.  What library should I use for doing that?

I'm using Linux Ubuntu 11.04.

---

I have tried use JMF, but when i run JMFINIT i had got error, this that error

```
JavaSound Capture Supported = true
JavaSoundAuto: Committed ok
Name = v4l:ð?*ð?*ia_protocol_v4l_V4LCapture_nOp:0
Trying 4 320 240
Trying 3 160 120
Trying 3 320 240
Trying 3 640 480
Trying 3 176 144
Trying 3 352 288
Trying 3 768 576
Trying 4 160 120
Trying 4 320 240
Trying 4 640 480
Trying 4 176 144
Trying 4 352 288
Trying 4 768 576
Trying 5 160 120
Trying 5 320 240
Trying 5 640 480
Trying 5 176 144
Trying 5 352 288
Trying 5 768 576
Trying 6 160 120
Trying 6 320 240
Trying 6 640 480
Trying 6 176 144
Trying 6 352 288
Trying 6 768 576
Trying 7 160 120
Trying 7 320 240
Trying 7 640 480
Trying 7 176 144
Trying 7 352 288
Trying 7 768 576
Trying 8 160 120
Trying 8 320 240
Trying 8 640 480
Trying 8 176 144
Trying 8 352 288
Trying 8 768 576
Trying 9 160 120
Trying 9 320 240
Trying 9 640 480
Trying 9 176 144
Trying 9 352 288
Trying 9 768 576
Trying 10 160 120
Trying 10 320 240
Trying 10 640 480
Trying 10 176 144
Trying 10 352 288
Trying 10 768 576
Trying 11 160 120
Trying 11 320 240
Trying 11 640 480
Trying 11 176 144
Trying 11 352 288
Trying 11 768 576
Trying 12 160 120
Trying 12 320 240
Trying 12 640 480
Trying 12 176 144
Trying 12 352 288
Trying 12 768 576
Trying 13 160 120
Trying 13 320 240
Trying 13 640 480
Trying 13 176 144
Trying 13 352 288
Trying 13 768 576
Trying 14 160 120
Trying 14 320 240
Trying 14 640 480
Trying 14 176 144
Trying 14 352 288
Trying 14 768 576
Trying 15 160 120
Trying 15 320 240
Trying 15 640 480
Trying 15 176 144
Trying 15 352 288
Trying 15 768 576
java.lang.Error: Can't open video card 1
java.lang.Error: Can't open video card 2
java.lang.Error: Can't open video card 3
java.lang.Error: Can't open video card 4
java.lang.Error: Can't open video card 5
java.lang.Error: Can't open video card 6
java.lang.Error: Can't open video card 7
java.lang.Error: Can't open video card 8
java.lang.Error: Can't open video card 9
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the Java Media Framework. On linux i would expect that the webcam is represented somewhere in the dev directory, and you would be opening that as a file and reading data into something from JMF. I haven't done it myself however

Found this link for you though.. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=716250

Comment: That would be good info to put in your question... Your question hasn't been upvoted, probably because you haven't told us what you've tried and where you searched.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do below with VLC in Linux, you can do the same with VLCJ, the Java binding for libVLC, the VLC engine used in VLC...

http://chriscarey.com/wordpress/2009/01/04/streaming-a-webcam-in-linux-with-vlc/

http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/wiki/Streaming